# C# code changes not reflected through IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a small web app written in C# that is published through IIS. If I change the code in the source file, the change is not reflected when I refresh the browser. I can literally delete all the code from the source file, save it, recycle the app pool in IIS, clear the browser cache, refresh the browser and it STILL loads the old code!
Any thoughts?

Comment: Try rebuilding and publishing your web project from VS

Comment: Go to the IIS Manager, find your application, right click on your site and click on Explore. Are you sure you are editing files in this path? Also right click on your site and and in Manage Application click on Browse. Do you see your changes?

Comment: note that only razor views (e.g. .cshtml files) are dynamically compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer goes to Akshay Mahajan. I don't see the ability to upvote his/her response. As for Mahdi, the source file in my question was referring to exactly what you mentioned.